# Size of the file is changing after upload in spring

Tags: java, spring, file

I am trying to upload an apk file in my local spring java web application, but the size of the file is getting changed after its uploaded as a result of which checksum is failing.

basically the size of the file on disk is different than the size of the file I receive in my application.

I am completely clueless, I am not sure how to go on debugging this.

PS: the temp file(tmp folder) which gets created during uploading has increased size than the one I originally upload.

code :

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/app", method = RequestMethod.POST, consumes = MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA)
public Application upload(@RequestParam(value = "apkFile", required=false) MultipartFile apkFile, 
                          @RequestParam(value = "iconFile", required=false) MultipartFile iconFile, 
                          @RequestParam Map<String, String> params, HttpServletRequest request, 
                          Authentication authentication) {
    //process
}
```

Dependencies I use

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>commons-fileupload</groupId>
    <artifactId>commons-fileupload</artifactId>
    <version>1.3.2</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
    <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
    <version>2.5</version>
</dependency>
```

Html code I use :

Upload File Request Page

```
    <form method="POST"
        action="http://localhost:8080/devicemanagement_administration/admin/api/v1/application/app"
        enctype="multipart/form-data">
        type(binary,icon or screenshot): <input type="text" name="contentType"><br />
         tenantId(ibm or google): <input type="text" name="tenantId"><br />
        <br /> platform(android or ios): <input type="text" name="platform"><br />
        File to upload: <input type="file" id="apkFile" name="apkFile"><br /> content
        <br /> <input type="submit" value="Upload"> Press here to
        upload the file!
    </form>

</body>
</html>
```

PS:i tried uploading text and json files, the size doesnt change after uploading.. only most apks are causing issues.

Comment: They are two different files or you are doing something wrong in the code that receives the upload. First pass is trying with another file - if the problem is still there the server is the problem, otherwise you may be picking the wrong file or overwriting it.

Comment: added the code snippet i use in the question. i check the size of the file just after the control enters the method by putting the breakpoint... there are many files for which the size is different and there are only a few files for which the size is not changing.

Comment: I use tomcat 8.0.33 and jdk 1.8, incase if this info is useful

Comment: Does the form (jsp or html) have multi part in the encoding part?

Comment: http://www.htmlcodetutorial.com/forms/_FORM_ENCTYPE.html

Comment: tomcat/webserver mime type set up for apk? https://www.google.co.in/search?q=tomcat+mime+type+apk

Comment: Please post the HTML of the form and [check (SpringBoot documentation for example)](https://spring.io/guides/gs/uploading-files/) that limits are not exceeded

Comment: @tgkprog : The upload method which i have written just saves the apk file to a secure location after verifying its checksum, so there is no parsing of the apk file i am doing.  ... I have updated the question with the html i use.. if there is a way to share the sample apks i use to test, i am okay to share that as well, i dont know how to share though..

Comment: @tgkprog : i tried after setting up with tomcat/webserver mime type as well.. no luck still :(

Comment: is there any chance that using commons-fileupload and commons-io is creating an issue? I tried uploading apk/zip etc with only commons-fileupload and it is working fine. Can you check if there are any conflicting dependencies

Comment: Use a plain servlet with apache file upload code to test

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally figured out what was the issue,

I  had put a logging filter to this application which would alter the request in that  logging filter. Removed the part where the request is altered. working fine now.